# How to manipulate translateY() based on offset().top using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I am playing with a little jQuery snippet that changes the position of a fixed element by manipulating the "top" value based on the offset of the element from the window.

I have created this jsFiddle to better illustrate what I mean: 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0632ve8/7/)

Here is the simple jQuery code:

```
function switchIt () {
  $('.text-two').each(function() {
    $(this).css('top',
      $('.text-one').offset().top -  $(this).closest('.content').offset().top
    );
  });
};

$(document).scroll(function() {switchIt();});

switchIt();
```

It works well but I would actually like to change the position using the css function `translateY()` instead of `top`.

For example: `top: 100px;` shoud be `transform: translateY(100px);`

I know this should be easy and I'm a embarrassed to show the steps I've tried to get this to work. I'm missing something very simple but somehow can't find out where.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Just use `.css()` to set the "transform" property to whatever string you want.

Comment: `.css('transform','translateY('+ .. + ')')`

Comment: *"I have created this jsFiddle to better illustrate what I mean"* Please make runnable examples **here, on-site** rather than off-site. (You can provide a fiddle link *as well*, if you like.) You can do that using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Three reasons: 1. People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; 2. links rot; and 3. People can easily click a button to copy your snippet to their answer and then update it, providing their answer here on-site as a complete, runnable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change top with transfrom AND remove `100px` which is the default top value added in the CSS:

```js
function switchIt () {
  $('.text-two').each(function() {
    $(this).css('transform','translateY('+(
      $('.text-one').offset().top -  $(this).closest('.content').offset().top-100)+'px)'
    );
  });
};

$(document).scroll(function() {switchIt();});

switchIt();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

}

.content div {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.text-one {
  position: fixed;
  color: blue
}

.text-two {
  position: absolute;
  color: white
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="content">
  <div class="text-one">Scroll down to see</div> 
</section>

<section class="content blue">
  <div class="text-two">Scroll down to see this Text changing</div> 
</section>
```

Or simply remove the top from the CSS:

```js
function switchIt () {
  $('.text-two').each(function() {
    $(this).css('transform','translateY('+(
      $('.text-one').offset().top -  $(this).closest('.content').offset().top)+'px)'
    );
  });
};

$(document).scroll(function() {switchIt();});

switchIt();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

}

.content div {
  left: 100px;
}

.text-one {
  position: fixed;
  top:100px;
  color: blue
}

.text-two {
  position: absolute;
  color: white
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="content">
  <div class="text-one">Scroll down to see</div> 
</section>

<section class="content blue">
  <div class="text-two">Scroll down to see this Text changing</div> 
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

just assign the transform property of the style property for the element

```js
//using jquery
$('#one').css({transform:"translateY(100px)"});
//using vanilla JavaScript
document.getElementById('two').style.transform = "translateY(100px)";
```

```css
#one, #two{
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='one'>one</div>
<div id='two'>two</div>
```

So your code snippet would look like:

```
function switchIt () {
$('.text-two').each(function() {
    $(this).css('transform',
        "translateY("+($('.text-one').offset().top -  $(this).closest('.content').offset().top)+"px)"
    );
});
};

$(document).scroll(function() {switchIt();});

switchIt();
```

here's a link to your fiddle working with the translateY http://jsfiddle.net/4mnty3v7/

Comment: This works and I have not downvoted it. I accepted the other answer because it was a bit more helpful for understanding why this actually works.

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann oh, no, you're fine. That was the correct answer selection as temani actually took the time to transport your fiddle here. I was just curious if someone had constructive criticism... or was just trigger happy. ^_^;